# Trying to Understand a Functions and Scope issue

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I am getting a bit confused with how python deals with the scopes. I understand where Global, Enclosed and Local variables are (at least I think I do :D).
I read the following paragraph in Learn Python 5th edition:

> When you use an unqualified name inside a function, Python searches up to four scopes — the local (L) scope, then the local scopes of any enclosing (E) defs and lambdas, then the global (G) scope, and then the built-in (B) scope — and stops at the first place the name is found. If the name is not found during this search, Python reports an error. (page 448)

Now I don't understand why example 1 works, while the example 2 does not.

## Example 1

```py
def box2():
    def box1():
        total = price + tip
        print(total)
    price = 1
    tip = 1
    box1()
box2()
```

## Example 2

```py
def box1():
    total = price + tip
    print(total)

def box2():
    price = 1
    tip = 1
    box1()
box2()
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Because `box2` is not considered an enclosing scope for `box1` - it's a completely separate scope

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement

Comment: Scope is based on lexical enclosure, not call sequence.

Comment: why is that? wasn't it called inside of box2(), so it is called within its scope?

Comment: Would Example 1 have made more sense if you removed every line with `box2` in it, so both the definition of `box1` and the code leading up to its being called were global?

Comment: @Adam What you are thinking is basically dynamic scoping, but Python uses (and so do most languages, especially modern ones) *lexical* scoping.

Comment: The call to box 1 is made from scope of box2, but *lexically* (i.e. the way the code is written - specifically, because the definition of box 1 is _outside_ the definition of box2 - box2 is not an enclosing scope for the definition of box1, so box1 cannot refer to variables in that scope. ‘Why’? Well it has to work somehow and the way you want it to work would be very very complex if not impossible to manage.

Comment: @ScottHunter , yes that would make sense and I understand that. But then I guess my understanding of the paragraph I quoted is not clear. Doesn't the paragraph mean that the function will search for a variable name in the 4 scopes, and if it doesn't find it, it will produce an error?

Comment: @Adam it doesn't *matter where it is called*, it matters where it is defined. in example 2`box1` was defined in the global scope, it doesn't have any enclosing scope from another function, because it wasn't *defined* in the scope of another function.

Comment: You’re not getting what ‘the local scope of any enclosing defs’ means - the key word is ‘enclosing’. In example 2, the definition of box2 does not enclose the definition of box, as it does in example 1.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , ok so because i defined box1 in the global scope, box1 consideres itself as the local, the global as global, and there is no enclosed variable.
So it doesn't search from the location of the call but rather from the location of the definition?

Comment: @Adam again, *yes*, that is what *lexical scoping means*, as opposed to *dynamic scoping*. Note, in dynamic scoping, the enclosing scope is *dynamic* based on where the function is *called*. Not a lot of languages support that behavior.

Comment: great, I think i finally get it.
I will read further into lexical scoping to make sure i got it.
Thank you very much to everyone who has help !! :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important bit of the paragraph is this:

> Python searches ... the local scopes of any **enclosing** (E) defs ...

"Enclosing" means where it is defined:

- In example 1, `box1` is defined **inside** `box2` (i.e. in the scope of `box2`), so `box2` is an enclosing scope of `box1`.
- In example 2, `box1` is defined **outside** `box2` (i.e. **not** in the scope of `box2`), so `box2` is **not** an enclosing scope of `box1`.

<sub>Due credit to [UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep), [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar), and especially [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) for explaining it so well in the comments</sub>